# system cannot find the file specified exception, when i want to save RSA Key in Key Container

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, encryption-asymmetric

I want to upload a text file that contains my private key to save in Key Container on web host.

I use below to save the keys:

```
var pk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fuPrivateKey.FileBytes);
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();
csp.KeyContainerName = "Name";
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, csp);
rsa.FromXmlString(pk);
Message = "Key Saved";
```

and this for encryption and decryption:

```
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters()
{
       KeyContainerName = "Name",
       Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey
};
      RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, csp);
```

I don't have in localhost but I got below error in web host when i want to save keys:

> Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.

Then I used `csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;` while storing keys and  my problem is solved but when i want to see if the key is exists like below it seems that doesnt exsit.(and problem in encrypting and decrypting)

How should I use flag some way that my problem will be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `CspParameters` with the below flag when i want to **store the keys**:

```
Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
```

and the below flag when i want to encrypt ,decrypt and **check existing of keys**:

```
Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey|CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
```